# @Html.Action("Method", "Controller") is rendering my Layout

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have a Layout page, and at the bottom, I have code that calls a method on a controller, and returns a partial view.

Locally, it works. But when I deploy to a server, it seems that the `@Html.Action("Method", "Controller")` renders my layout again.

Is `Html.Action` the right thing to do? I need to render a partial section by calling a controller method. It needs to return my partial view populated from the controller.

I thought `@Html.Partial` or `@Html.RenderPartial` would have been more correct - however, they don't seem to accept the arguments I need (Controller and Method).

Comment: You can replace it by `@{ Html.RenderAction }` to be more efficient. But `@Html.Action` is also perfectly right thing to do. May be you are missing something.

Comment: Can you show the code of the action you're rendering?

Comment: Your answer was right. I was returning ViewResult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're returning a `ViewResult` instead of `PartialViewResult` in your action. The former, when rendered, contains also your master page.

When you compare both classes you'll see, that the major difference is missing `MasterName` in `PartialViewResult`. When you use `ViewResult`, master is taken e.g. from `_ViewStart.cshtml`.

Comment: This was indeed the case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Put

```
@{
    Layout = null; 
}
```

on the top (if you have `@model`, put below it) of your partial view, which returns your controller.

Comment: This also resolved the issue! Thanks. went with the returning of the "PartialViewResult" as it seemed more correct.